# Why does Doctrine return me an associative array with a gap in the keys when fetching?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am building an app with Symfony.
I've got a Doctrine entity that contains (among other properties) a collection of another Entity (forming a OneToMany association).

```
Class OuterEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InnerEntity", mappedBy="outer", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $inners;
}
```

In my `OuterEntityController`, in the `updateOuterEntityAction` method, i do the following :

- parse the request
- get the updated Outer from db
- modify it according to the request
- call `flush()` on the entity manager
- call `findAll()` on the OuterEntity repository
- return the OuterEntity list to the client in a JsonResponse in order to notify it of the new state of the db. Since I use a JsonResponse, I let Symfony do the serialization (very probably with json_encode).

Everything is allright except when I delete one or more `InnerEntity` in the association. The issue does not come from the removal, but from the returned json format. Most of the times, the `inners` I get are under the form of a simple array:

```
{"inners":[{inner1},{inner2},...]}
```

, which is fine for me. But after a removal from this association (in the example, I assume the 2nd one was deleted), I get an array like this:

```
{"inners":{"0":{inner1},"2":{inner2},"3":{...},...}
```

Furthermore, this issue doesn't happen if the last `Inner` is deleted (or several `Inners` all located at the end of the array).

My supposition is that Doctrine places the association in an associative array and when json_encode serializes this array, it renders in the first format if the indexation is normal (0, 1, 2...), or in the second format if the indexation is broken (0, 2, 3...).

So my question is now : why doctrine does not place the result in a "normally indexed" array after a removal?
I think there's something going on with Doctrine's caching mechanism, but I can't figure exactly what. Maybe it's because the entity manager still considers the deleted entities. But I thought that the entity manager was cleared after the flush, isn't it?
I tried to call `clear()` on the entity manager, but I've had some strange behaviour and quickly gave up.

I'd be glad if one of you could point the mistake I am making.

Comment: This is partially because of how json_encode works, if passed an array containing numerical keys with no gaps it will serialize into your first example. However if passed an array where a key is missing in the line they it gets serialized as an object. Depending on how you are actually doing the serialization there may be some different ways of fixing this. Can you update your code to show how you are serializing your object?

Comment: This is indeed standard PHP behaviour: [Link](https://3v4l.org/0FCYj).

Comment: @Chausser : yes indeed, that's part of my reasoning, that's what I called "normal / abnormal indexation" (maybe my explanation was not clear -- sorry for my english).
The question now is : why do I get this kind of array with a missing key ?

Comment: You could work around this issue, by using the JmsSerialiserBundle.

Comment: @SamJanssens : Thx for the tip. Maybe I'll end using this bundle. But for the moment, I will try to resolve the issue directly.

Comment: you could e.g. do a `refresh` before your findAll, this will return DB values in an ungaped order, otherwise you return managed values from EntityManager which contains gaps.

Comment: @LBA: `refresh`-ing the entity manager was not the solution, but `clear`-ing it solved my problem. I don't know why it did not work the first time I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is on my side of the keyboard.

I don't know why, but I retried to `clear` the entity manager today, and everything works just fine as I first expected. I must have made a really dumb move at my first try.

Thanks everybody for the help, and sorry for the inconvenience.